# Idiom meaning not expressing opinion

Tags: expressions, idioms, formality

I am looking for an appropriate formal expression when we want to say that a person should not express their opinions, yet bow their head and be part of what the society considers normal and acceptable ? I am writing a motivational letter for a scholarship and I cannot come up with an appropriate expression. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This would appear to be the same as ["The nail that pops up is always hammered down"](/q/119705), which contains quite a few answers.

Comment: Answered at [Are there counterpart English expressions to Japanese proverb, "the nail that pops up is always hammered down?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119705/are-there-counterpart-english-expressions-to-japanese-proverb-the-nail-that-po)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant expressions include:

*[toe the line](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/toe_the_line), [toe the party line](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/toe_the_line)* - expressive of conformity and a meek acceptance of authority

> Radio stations are pretty much forced to *toe the line* since they rely
>   heavily on record companies for ad dollars and listener-grabbing perks
>   like contests, interviews and concerts.

*(don't) [make waves](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/make_waves)* - don't cause a disturbance

> Being part of the jeans generation is an affirmation of the positive
>   aspects of life, and indicates a willingness to defy convention and
>   question tradition, rather than keep a low profile and avoid *making
>   waves.*

*(don't) [rock the boat](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rock_the_boat)* - don't disturb the status quo, upsetting everyone

> They want to be sure that nobody *rocks the boat* and no major donors
>   are offended.

*(don't) [stick your neck out](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stick_one's_neck_out)* - don't expose yourself to (social) danger by making yourself noticeable - this example also includes [*keep your head down*,](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/keep_one's_head_down) also potentially useful

> You *stuck your neck out* when others *kept their heads down* and their
>   mouths shut.

*(don't) [put your head over the parapet](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-your-head-over-above-the-parapet)* - similar to *don't stick your neck out,* but with more emphasis on risking upsetting someone

> It is unfortunately not ‘politically correct’ in Wales to *stick one’s
>   head above the parapet* and voice these concerns as I am doing.

Example sentences are taken from the dictionary references given, except for the one immediately above which is from [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-stick-ones-head-above-the-parapet.2166937/).

As an alternative way of going about things, it seems to me that what you describe in your question does sound like quite a Japanese situation and the Japanese proverb, [*deru kugi (kui) wa utareru*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fgandon/miscellaneous/japan/) - commonly rendered in English language texts about Japan as *the nail (stake) that sticks up/out is hammered down* - does sound like a reasonable thing to refer to in this situation. It's far closer in spirit to what you ask for than any of the English idioms I can think of.

Edit: After posting I saw the comment by Andrew Leach, also referring to this Japanese expression.

(Side note: as you may come across this when doing your research, the *kui/kugi* thing is to do with construction techniques and a certain purism - traditional Chinese and Japanese building techniques don't use nails; wooden stakes 'lock' blocks together. *Kui* seems more common in online references, but I've only ever heard people say *kugi* ...and English renderings invariably go for *nail*, as it very sensibly sidesteps the need for just the kind of explanation I'm giving you now!)